# URL rewrite - make exception

Tags: exception, url-rewriting

My url-rewrites works perfectly after receiving some help here. However, I can't access my admin2-folder. I got the following code in my .htaccess file:
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test-site/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin2/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When trying to access localhost/test-site/admin2, it just redirects me to localhost/test-site/admin2/?site=admin2. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
RewriteRule ^admin2($|/) - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2&id=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&cmd=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```